# Using Firebase to handle data from HTTP POST

Tags: http-post, firebase

I'm creating a web app that will function as an endpoint for an experiment that will use a `RockBlock` unit.  The data that comes from the unit is routed through the Iridium satellite network and then send to the endpoint via a http POST. We're returning, 'OK'(Status Code:`200`), immediately after receiving data.

I'd like to:

1. Store the data,
2. Visualize one parameter of these data in a `x-y plot` in real-time,
3. Display other data parameters numerically in a dashboard type layout.

Can firebase help me quickly stand up this sort of application?  Are there some examples of an implementation like this available for me to look at in firebase "knowledge base"?

Thanks ahead for your assistance,

*P.S. Here is some sample PHP code that I'm starting with that shows one way to get the data, decode the payload data (in hex), and send a response.*

```
$imei = $_POST["imei"];
$momsn = $_POST["momsn"];
$transmit_time = $_POST["transmit_time"];
$iridium_latitude = $_POST["iridium_latitude"];
$iridium_longitude = $_POST["iridium_longitude"];
$iridium_cep = $_POST["iridium_cep"];
$data = $_POST["data"];

$decoded = pack('H*', $data);

echo "OK";
```

Comment: Firebase REST API is covered [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/), including an A-Z guide. Also, this is way too broad. This isn't a question, it's a request for an application.

Comment: That's correct. Assuming that you don't care about your data being writable publicly, you can start in 49 seconds.  If you need some sort of security, then you will need a security rule and a token generated by a trusted device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase to store your information and some JS framework to display it. If you want to use Firebase REST services, you are warned that you will need to implement a server somewhere that using your Firebase secret, will generate a token that your device can use to POST on Firebase. Alternatively you can feed your device with your Firebase secret if you trust the device.

Comment: There are a lot of alternatives to using secrets and generating tokens; this is unrelated to using the REST API and more related to system architecture and security constraints.